# USB Cameras Constantly Disconnect

Tags: usb, camera, data-corruption, disconnect, jpeg

I am working in a project that requires 5 USB Cameras to be connected and ruining constantly. However they all end up disconnected after 30 minutes. One by one they drop with some error codes.I have change computers and updated the bios but the problem persist in Ubuntu 18,20 and 22. The only way to reconnect them is by unplugging and plugging the USB cable witch is very time consuming and not a solution. I am using A PC ruining Ubuntu 20.04. This are the errors that they produce.

```
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment

[ WARN:0@27.903] global cap_v4l.cpp:872 requestBuffers VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/v4l/by-path/pci-0000:08:00.3-usb-0:3:1.0-video-index0): failed VIDIOC_REQBUFS: errno=19 (No such device)

Corrupt JPEG data: 82 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd6
Corrupt JPEG data: 35 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd7

[ WARN:0@47.734] global loadsave.cpp:248 findDecoder imread_('/dev/v4l/by-path/pci-0000:02:00.0-usb-0:1:1.0-video-index0'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity


-- Logs begin at Mon 2023-07-03 22:14:38 EDT, end at Sun 2023-07-09 20:33:16 EDT. --
Jul 09 20:23:35 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX code.desktop[21380]: [main 2023-07-10T00:23:35.230Z] update#setState checking for updates
Jul 09 20:23:35 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX code.desktop[21380]: [main 2023-07-10T00:23:35.235Z] update#setState available for download
Jul 09 20:24:01 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jul 09 20:24:06 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jul 09 20:24:07 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jul 09 20:24:12 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jul 09 20:24:12 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jul 09 20:24:17 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jul 09 20:24:17 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jul 09 20:24:23 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jul 09 20:24:23 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jul 09 20:24:28 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jul 09 20:24:28 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jul 09 20:24:33 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jul 09 20:24:34 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jul 09 20:24:39 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jul 09 20:24:39 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:08:00.3: WARN Event TRB for slot 3 ep 2 with no TDs queued?
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: uvcvideo 6-3:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: uvcvideo 6-3:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: uvcvideo 6-3:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: uvcvideo 6-3:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: uvcvideo 6-3:1.1: Failed to resubmit video URB (-19).
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (II) config/udev: removing device 3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (II) event18 - 3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera: device removed
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:82
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 6-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: usb 6-3: Found UVC 1.00 device 3.0 USB Camera (15aa:1555)
Jul 09 20:24:42 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX kernel: input: 3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:08:00.3/usb6/6-3/6-3:1.0/input/input182
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device 3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera (/dev/input/event18)
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (**) 3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for '3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera'
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event18 13:82 fd 85 paused 0
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (**) 3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera: always reports core events
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event18"
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (II) event18 - 3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (II) event18 - 3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera: device is a keyboard
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (II) event18 - 3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera: device removed
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:08:00.3/usb6/6-3/6-3:1.0/input/input182/>
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "3.0 USB Camera: 3.0 USB Camera" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Jul 09 20:24:43 kc-B550I-AORUS-PRO-AX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1436]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
```

Comment: Do the system logs say anything interesting? Read `man journalctl` and use the `--since=` and `--before=` options. Use `sudo journalctl  ...` . Do any of the devices/hubs go into a low-power sleep state? Are your USB hubs sufficiently powered? The messages you show look like the connection was dropped by the other end, in the middle of a transfer.

Comment: Thanks for taking interest. I Added the --since= report to the question. I hope we can solve this together, this problem have being bugging me for a year now. I have used supplemental power for the USB ports before but it did not solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple internet search for "`device descriptor read/8, error -110`" led me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110 which says, in part,

> USB error -110 means "Timeout expired before the transfer completed",
> which could be caused by anything. Most commonly, it's because power
> was exceeded; the host could not provide enough electric power ..

.

but read it for yourself.

Thanks for formatting the log text.